# Laravel error 429 (Too Many Requests) : How to check and log requests count?

Tags: laravel

I have the following error message in my console:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 429 (Too Many Requests)

So, my question is, from where can I get the number of requests to check and log when I'm close to the limit ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

##### In client side, you can check the response headers

```
x-ratelimit-limit: 60
x-ratelimit-remaining: 59
```

[image]

if you send requests by `axios`

```
axios.get(`/api/users`)
    .then(({ data, headers }) => {
        console.log(headers['x-ratelimit-limit']);
    });
```

---

##### In server side, you can add a middleware like this

```
php artisan make:middleware LogRequestLimit
```

register it in **app\Http\Kernel.php**

```php
    protected $middleware = [
        ...
        \App\Http\Middleware\LogRequestLimit::class,
    ];
```

**app\Http\Middleware\LogRequestLimit.php**

```php
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;

class LogRequestLimit
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        \Log::debug($response->headers->get('x-ratelimit-limit'));

        return $response;
    }
}
```

[image]